# Expand a partition

Tags: move-partition

I want to increase the size of partition `/dev/sda2 (root partition)` by including the unallocated space of size 2 GB as shown in the screen shot below. How to achieve this?

[image: HDD structure]

My laptop has 2 Operating systems of Ubuntu. The one where I logged in is visible in the screen-shot. It has `/dev/sda8` as root partition and `/dev/sda7` as boot partition.
The other Ubuntu is on the top to the image having `/dev/sda2` as `root partition` & `/dev/sda1` as `boot partition`. The `home partition` of this is `/dev/sda5`.

> EDIT

As per the solution offered in the answer by Tomas, I shrank the extended partition `/dev/sda4` by taking the unallocated 2 GB out of it to the left of the extended partition. Then I moved the `/dev/sda3` to the right of the unallocated space of 2GB and finally expanded `/dev/sda2` by including the 2 GB into it.

But the issue I encountered due to this is that now I'm unable to boot into the Ubuntu shown in the bottom of the image having `/dev/sda7` as `boot partiton`. Though I'm able to boot into the other Ubuntu.

So, I would like to get a safer method of doing the task, i.e. how to expand `/dev/sda2`!

Comment: Using gpart is risky. You should use mounts to expand capacity. Of course, the use of LVM better.

Answer (score 1):

The unallocated 2G are on the extended partition `/dev/sda4` and there's the `/dev/sda3` swap between the extended partition and `/dev/sda2`. What you need to do then is:

1. Resize `/dev/sda4` so that the 2G space is not a part of it.
2. Move `/dev/sda3` swap to the right by 2G.
3. Extend `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: Oh a problem occurred. I've 2 Ubuntu installed. One root partition is /dev/sda2 & the other /dev/sda8. What i did , after that /dev/sda2 is booting but not /dev/sda8 Gparted successfully did the task but had 2 warnings which i missed to see. I'm addressing to @utopic also. What has gone wrong with the other ubuntu which is shown in screenshot having /dev/sda8 as root partition ?

Comment: @Ravi One might have been a warning to backup. If you resized the encrypted `/dev/sda4`, that might have been a bad way to go.

Comment: Yes as you know `dev/sda4` is resized? Was that encrypted? I got that 2GB unallocated space by shrinking `/dev/sda5` which is home partition of that ubuntu. Yes yes resizing `dev/sda4` might be the problem as the boot & root partitions are lying inside it. But both boot & root partition weren't touched!

Comment: @Ravi `/dev/sda9` looks like the home partition. The extended partition is encrypted as there's the small key icon there next to the partition name. My guess is they're LVM. I think you should open a new question about how to recover your OS. Include the output of `df -h` in it and describe what you've done and what the problem is now.

Comment: @Ravi I should have warned you in my answer about the encryption. Sorry.

Comment: Its not encrypted. The key icon is there if one of the included logical partition is locked (or is having key icon). I booted from live USB & opened gparted. I found the extended partition had key icon & the linux swap `/dev/sda10` inside that also had key icon. I right clicked the swap partition & pressed `swapoff` & the icon vanished from swap as well as from the extended partition `/dev/sda4`. The lock icon signifies you can't edit it. As in the beginning I wasn't able to resize the extended partition `/dev/sda4` as you mentioned in your answer, I came to know all this.

Comment: Yes sorry /dev/sda5 is home partition of the other ubuntu whose root partition is /dev/sda2. Sorry again for the mistake.

Comment: I'll edit my question shortly for more clarity mentioning about both ubuntu. Sorry for missing this point in my question.

Comment: @Ravi It looks better now that the partitions are only locked. Encryption often means problems. You should start another question on OS recovery as that's a completely different matter. This one's closed.

Comment: Shall I close this or just wait for me to edit this Q a bit. The reason is this Q intended to get solution as to how increase the size of the root partition `/dev/sda2` by including the unallocated space of 2 GB. So what solution is there so that this issue that has risen now shouldn't arise and successfully the size gets increased by including that 2 GB.

Comment: @Ravi You don't have to close it. What I mean is that you looked for an answer, you got it and you followed. As you commented, task completed. You can wait for another answer and you can edit your question to include what happened and stress in your question that you're looking for a safer way to do what you're asking about. GParted warns you each time that the operation involves risk. You may look for another tool. That's ok. But restoring the OS and repairing the damage is another question.

Comment: Yes thats fine. I'll shortly open up the new question.

Comment: I've edited this question and started the new connected question. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355279/how-to-recover-ubuntu

Comment: I am able to boot into the OS which earlier I wasn't able to do. I didn't do anything specifically for that. Simply I booted into the another OS and now I again tried booting in the OS which was failing earlier. Now I succeeded. You can look at the link to the related Q also.

Comment: @Ravi Good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend gparted, a frontend for parted command line tool.

Other that that any partition manager will be able to do this.

Comment: That's exactly what's in the question image.