# How to recover Ubuntu?

Tags: partition, system-recovery

This question has come from the [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354878/expand-a-partition) I asked in this site.

My laptop has 2 Operating systems of Ubuntu as can be seen in the screen-shot below. The one where I logged in is visible in the image. It has `/dev/sda8` as root partition `/dev/sda7` as boot partition & `/dev/sda9` as home partition. The other Ubuntu is on the top of the image having `/dev/sda2` as root partition & `/dev/sda1` as boot partition. The home partition of this is `/dev/sda5`.

[image: gparted display of 2 Ubuntu OS]

I wanted to expand root partition `/dev/sda2` of the OS as shown in the top of the image. For that, I shrank the extended partition /dev/sda4 by taking the unallocated 2 GB out of it to the left of the extended partition. Then I moved the /dev/sda3 to the right of the unallocated space of 2GB and finally expanded /dev/sda2 by including the 2 GB into it.

But the issue I encountered due to this is that now I'm unable to boot into the Ubuntu shown in the bottom of the image having /dev/sda7 as boot partiton. Though I'm able to boot into the other Ubuntu.

What is the reason for not being able to boot into the OS? Is it that the root and the boot partition of this OS was inside the extended partition `/dev/sda4` as a result of which shrinking the extended partition cased the failure to boot? Though the boot partition `dev/sda7` & the root partition `/dev/sda8` were untouched.

And the other question is now how to recover that Ubuntu OS?

> EDIT

I'm able to boot back now on the Ubuntu OS which was failing to boot earlier. I would just describe what I did after the expansion of the partition so that one can make out what may be the issue.

See, 2 days back I expanded the partition as mentioned in my Q. After that I immediately tried to log into the OS which was getting failed to boot. I tried thrice continuously but failed each time to boot and was getting hanged with a cursor visible (without blinking) in the top left of the screen. After that I booted into the other OS. Then now I again tried booting into the one which was failing earlier. But now I successfully booted.

So, is it that as one OS was failing, so after booting into the other, some changes were made in the bootloader that enabled the booting for the OS which was earlier failing? I don't know.

Comment: 1. I wonder if you saw the BIG FAT warning everytime you try to shrink/extend a partition, which states something like: "WARNING: Shrinking or extending partitions of an already installed system may cause the system to be unable to boot!". 2. Please try to make it clear, what is installed on which partition and what you did exactly. I think you made a mistake in the explanation and it is extremely hard to understand which partition is for what because it's explained very confusingly anyway. Please try to rephrase it and check if you accidentally switched one /dev/sda partition with another.

Comment: @Akito I've rephrased the Q. If still anything you would like me to clarify, please let me know. No, I didn't switch one partition with another as pointed out.

Comment: @Akito I have edited my Q.

Comment: @tomas I've edited my Q.

Comment: Did you `update && upgrade` the system? If yes, it might've reconfigured the GRUB2 configuration which led to this result.

Comment: @Akito  yes yes you are absolutely right . In the meantime I had updated my other ubuntu using software updater. After that only I tried back booting the ubuntu which was earlier getting failed to boot.

Comment: @Akito though I'm able to recover the ubuntu, still this question is open to get what issue occurred when I edited the partitions that resulted in failure to boot.